# Zooming-in the image centered around the cursor with CSS

Tags: css

I have a map image, and I want to zoom in/out when I click on it. This code below zooms it, but I want to zoom-in the image centered around the location of the cursor and make horizontal-scroll appear. How can I do it with **only CSS**?

***CSS***

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

.container img{
    transition: transform 0.25s ease;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img{
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="container"><input id="zoomCheck" type="checkbox" />
<label for="zoomCheck">
<img src="map.jpg" />
</label></div>
```

Comment: You can do it using javascript. :D

Comment: CSS does not responds to click events on image. Use JS. Calculate location of mouse click and than zoom map and move it to fit click coordinates as center of zoomed image

Answer (score 1):

I created you the logic you can use. Just add the other functionality.

Basically, this is what you want.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zpobnetf/11/

How can you achieve it?

1. Get position of click (clientX, clienY)
2. Clone the image into a div with background image (src of the image clicked)
3. Position them depending on the position that was clicked on.

As you can see on my example. I subtract clientX and clientY by 75. It's because the box that I created has a size of 150x150. I just divide it by 2. So, I can position the #box at the center.

Hope you get it. Cheers! You can do it. Just believe!

```js
let mapa = document.getElementById('map'),
 box = document.getElementById('box');

mapa.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 let xPos = (e.clientX - 75),
   yPos = (e.clientY - 75);
    
  box.style.display = 'initial';
  box.style.top = `${yPos}px`;
  box.style.left = `${xPos}px`;
  box.style.backgroundPosition = `-${xPos}px -${yPos}px`;
});
```

```css
#box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: scale(1.4);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="map" src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png">

<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am looking for a solution with pure CSS. Isn't there a way around it?

Comment: Oh I see. There's no way for css solution right now. You need javascript to make effect like this. Because, css don't have trigger for mouse click event. So, css can't get the position of the image that was clicked on. Btw, sorry for answering it using javascript. I didn't see the note you put on top.